# How to scrape multiple data points that pop up after mouseover event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, mouseover

I am trying to scrape data from the following website:
https://prisjagt.dk/lyd-billede/horetelefoner-tilbehor/hovedtelefoner/apple-airpods-pro-2nd-generation-2022--p7054034

I would like to scrape data from the graph in the upper right called "Prishistorik", but the data only appears when hovering the mouse over specific points on the graph.

Using the code below, I managed to get one output. However, it seems that every point on the chart has the same xpath, so how can I scrape all the different dates and corresponding prices across the chart?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

DRIVER_PATH = r'd:\8278\Downloads\chromedriver.exe'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
browser.get("https://prisjagt.dk/lyd-billede/horetelefoner-tilbehor/hovedtelefoner/apple-airpods-pro-2nd-generation-2022--p7054034")
browser.maximize_window()

explicit_wait20 = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

try:
    prices = explicit_wait20.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#root > div > section > div.Content-sc-2fu3f8-2.hybPGh > div.PageContent-sc-1wgu331-5.fbKCSg > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div.StyledViewport-sc-7zjdbj-0.iDfoDl > header > div.ProductSummary-sc-16x82tr-1.cfOOAp > div.PriceHistoryLinkWrapper-sc-yn9z6-0.iQTEhC > a > div > div > div.PriceHistoryWrapper-sc-1yjg8cb-3.ejhsba > div > svg > g:nth-child(3) > rect')))
except TimeoutException:
    browser.refresh()

data = []

for p in prices:
    # Execute mouseover on the element
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(p).perform()

    mouseover = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/header/div[4]/div[1]/a/div/div/div[2]/div/div')))
    data.append(mouseover.text)

print(data[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you don't even need to use selenium to find the price history. You can use `requests`, calling **graphql** endpoint with some parameters gives you a list of price history under `data['product']['statistics']['nodes']`.

See [example call](https://prisjagt.dk/_internal/graphql?release=2022-10-04T13:30:05Z%7C784a9d4c&version=46f708&main=product&variables=%7B%22id%22:7054034,%22offset%22:0,%22section%22:%22statistics%22,%22statisticsTime%22:%221970-01-02%22,%22marketCode%22:%22dk%22,%22personalizationExcludeCategories%22:%5B%5D,%22recommendationsContextId%22:%22product-page%22,%22advized%22:false,%22priceHistory%22:true,%22importantDates%22:true,%22priceHistoryTable%22:true,%22priceTrend%22:true,%22medianPrice%22:true,%22campaignId%22:4,%22personalizationClientId%22:%22%22,%22pulseEnvironmentId%22:%22%22%7D).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not familiar with graphql, so could you please provide some example code or general approach for how you managed to retrieve that url?

Comment: This video by [Google Devs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1gAyQuIFQo&ab_channel=GoogleChromeDevelopers) covers the basics. Then you may want to learn some more about XHR requests [maybe here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb8gHvYlCFs&t=786s&ab_channel=CoreySchafer). Finally, you may want to check out [curl converter](https://curlconverter.com/) which rewrites the requests into python for you. If you found my answer helpful, feel free to accept it.